# What does Ajax really look like?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I just researching about Ajax for afew day (To use with Django Python framwork) But I found many result about Ajax.

1.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

2. 

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: actionUrl,
        ....
    });
```

3. 

```
fetch("api/xxx", {
    method: "post",
}
.then(...)
```

Does 3 of these is the same?

Comment: Yes, pretty much all do the same, the first 2 are AJAX, the 2nd is just using a 3rd party lib called jquery that uses ajax, your last is using `fetch`, I would use that one as it's the latest standard,..

Comment: Yes. 1. is the old way, 2. is the jQuery way nad 3. is the new way of doing an Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing three examples of ajax, which stands for asynchronous javascript and xml.

Ajax is in fact a development technique, which is basically "doing rest calls from javascript to get some data and dynamically change the page instead of reloading it completely".

If I'm not wrong, the first is plain javascript, the second is jquery and the third is some modern library which I don't know because I'm more into backend :D

Comment: The 3rd is not a lib, it's part of the browsers these days.  Nicely promise based..

Comment: thx, I haven't coded FE in plain javascript for long!